# Robot.txt blocking URLs with page parameter higher than 10

Tags: robots.txt

I was checking already for similar questions, but I don't think this specific case has been asked and answered yet.

I'd like to block all URLs with the page Parameter higher than 10 (I probably choose a lower value than 10).

```
Disallow: /events/world-wide/all-event-types/all?page=11
Allow : /events/world-wide/all-event-types/all?page=3
```

I have alot of similar URLS where the other "parameters" can change with some lists which have up almost 150 pages.

```
Disallow: /events/germany/triathlon/all?page=13
Allow : /events/germany/triathlon/all?page=4
```

How can I accomplish this without listing all the URLs (which is basically impossible)

Please let me emphasize again here that the page parameter is the important thing here.

I can probably do something like this:

```
Disallow: *?page=
Allow: *?page=(1-10)
```

What's the proper approach here?

Comment: You can't block with robots.txt. Robots.txt only tells bots what to crawl and what not to. If you want to block you should do it somewhere in your .htaccess/web.config or code base.

Comment: The question is of course related to blocking the robots :-) that crawl my page.

Comment: Even if you find a syntax which works for *some* clients, keep in mind that most bots probably support robots.txt as a quick afterthought. Anything that even approaches the margins of the syntax is probably risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The robots.txt "regEx" syntax is fairly limited so unfortunately it can result in unnecessarily large robots.txt files. Although the other answers address the primary use case, you might want to also consider adding some variants to account for shuffling of additional parameters.

```
Disallow: *?page=
Disallow: *&page=
Allow: *?page=1$
Allow: *?page=2$
Allow: *?page=3$
...
Allow: *?page=1&
Allow: *?page=2&
Allow: *?page=3&
...
Allow: *&page=1&
Allow: *&page=2&
Allow: *&page=3&
....
```

Comment: The page URL parameter is the only visible parameter, so it's always at the end with `?page=xxx` . If that wasn't the case, your answer is the most complete answer.... So I will take your answer as the correct answer. Even though I used my answer on the live version...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
 Allow: /*?page=1
 Allow: /*?page=2
 Allow: /*?page=3
 Allow: /*?page=4
 Allow: /*?page=5
 Allow: /*?page=6
 Allow: /*?page=7
 Allow: /*?page=8
 Allow: /*?page=9
 Allow: /*?page=10
 Disallow: /*?page=1*
 Disallow: /*?page=2*
 Disallow: /*?page=3*
 Disallow: /*?page=4*
 Disallow: /*?page=5*
 Disallow: /*?page=6*
 Disallow: /*?page=7*
 Disallow: /*?page=8*
 Disallow: /*?page=9*
```

So we allow pages from 1 to 10
And disallow pages higher, than 10.

You can read the [google docs there](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961&vid=1-635774236759752735-4102521869)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bazzilio for the nice try, but we programmers are lazy and try to avoid writing code as much as possible. The best I can come up with for now is the following (which works)

```
Disallow: *?page=
Allow: *?page=1$
Allow: *?page=2$
Allow: *?page=3$
Allow: *?page=4$
....
```

But isn't there a way to combine the Allow statements?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that robot.txt does not allow Regular Expressions. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/robots-txt-and-regular-expressions

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a clean way of combining the Allow: statements since the "regEx" for robots.txt is fairly limited. I added some variants as an answer since they wouldn't fit in this comment space.